# Получить и применить в запроссе значение Автоинкрементирующегося столбца (id)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Доброго времени! Задача такова: есть таблица пользователей содержит поля:

```
 id INT(9) auto increment
 name VARCHAR(255)
 login VARCHAR(255)
 pass VARCHAR(255)
```

в нее скрипт записывает массив пользователей имея только имена (Саша Маша Артур ...)
при том генерируя логин\пароль по дефолту на лету таки образом:
через функцию преобразуя имя в латиницу маша -> masha + id записи

делается так сначало записывается только имя:

```
$add->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)");
$add->bind_param('s',$name);    
$add = $add->execute();
```

потом извлекает id последней записи

```
$ref = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$ref = $ref->fetch_array();
```

и преобразовав имя в латиницу и прибавив в конец id генерирует логин к примеру masha239 и пароль md5('masha239');

вопрос можно ли как то еще при первом запросе узнать какой будет id у следующей записи что бы записать данные сразу за один заход в БД не прибегая к этим кругалям, а как то более элегантно одним запросом типа:

```
$add->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,login,pass) VALUES (".$name.",".latin($name).[id того что сейчас запишем].",".md5(latin($name).[id того что сейчас запишем]).")");
$add = $add->execute();
```

есть ли в sql какая то заготовленная на данный случай функция?

Comment: для получения значения вставленного инкремента используются соответствующие функции (`last_insert_id`). Узнать какой будет следующий инкрементный id  у вас не получится, ибо автоинкремент это не последовательность, там могут быть пропуски.

Comment: @Visman дак автор хочет на основе `id` формировать данные.

Comment: @teran, прочитал не внимательно.

Comment: Это не безопасно, зарегистрировав пару-тройку пользователей потенциальный хакер заметит закономерность и сможет достаточно легко подбирать пароли пользователей. Генерируйте пароли с использованием случайных чисел.

Comment: @Mike да я понимаю но это всего лишь генерация авторизационных данных по дефолту пользователи их получают а потом сами меняют их через личный кабинет, пароли возможно будут генерироваться по другому но вот логины как мне видится простейший способ исключить совпадения при записи это генерировать их с применением id

Comment: И да, если вы все таки хотите после вставки записи узнать ее id ни в коем случае не делайте так, как сейчас, до того как вы захотите получить id последней записи, другой процесс может вставить еще одного пользователя ! используйте, как вам сказали выше, last_insert_id (или аналогичную функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: @dantelol А тогда зачем вам id именно этой записи, последний id уже существующий в таблице на момент вставки записи такой же уникальный, как и тот, который будет назначен новой записи, так что можете даже прямо в insert подзапросом получать max(id)

Comment: @Mike рекомендую подумать, почему никакой уникальностью здесь и не пахнет.

Comment: @Ипатьев Если вы вдруг не заметили, я ТС ранее уже писал, что у него могут быть проблемы с получением id select сразу после вставки. И разумеется я отлично понимаю, что max(id) так же не дает гарантии, что двум вставкам не вернут одно значение. правда вероятность, что такое событие произойдет при добавлении пользователей с одинаковыми именами очень мала, хотя и есть...  Раз уж замечаете это в комментариях, предложите в своем ответе нормальное решение данной проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Нет, такой функции нет, и быть не может. В этом весь смысл формирования *уникального* идентификатора - он становится известным только после вставки, что гарантирует уникальность. Если же "узнавать заранее", то дело кончится наличием в таблице записей с одинаковым id, что будет полной бессмыслицей.

Comment: Всё-таки быть такая функция может. `nextval` в `postgresql` можно вызывать вне зависимости от insert и именно вызов nextval резервирует уникальное значение. Но в mysql - да, невозможно.

Comment: `nextval` делает совершенно иную вещь - она возвращает значение, которое при использовании гарантированно будет уникальным, ещё не существующим. Но именно при использовании - его генерация никак не связана с использованием, самого использования может и не быть. Т.е. это прогноз. В то время как автоинкремент - это итог, он является результатом уже состоявшегося использования.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать подзапросом выбирать id последней записи и прибавлять 1

`INSERT INTO users (name,login,pass) VALUES (".$name.",".latin($name).((SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1).",".md5(latin($name).((SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1)).")`